# Insert into DATE type in a SQL Server database with monthCalendar

Tags: c#, sql-server, date, time

I can't find a single thing on the web that explains how would I insert it

```
if (radioButton1.Checked) 
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Andrej\Desktop\B9PROBA\B9\B9\Database5.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");

    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ARB11StavkeRezervacije(RezervacijaID,RBR,KomadID,Datum,KolikoSedista) VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + comboBox1.SelectedValue + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString() + "')", conn);

    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        MessageBox.Show("Uspesno Uneti Podaci");
    }
    catch (Exception e1) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e1.Message); 
    }
    finally 
    {
        conn.Close(); 
    }
}
```

I always get an error that a string failed to convert to date.

I have no clue how to insert it

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: @Csharpclass, the parameter will not only address the security issue, it will fix your problem if you pass the `monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start` value as a `datetime` parameter instead of string. See [why parameters are a best practice](https://www.dbdelta.com/why-parameters-are-a-best-practice/).

Comment: @DanGuzman  My apologies for my ignorance.Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1):

You should use **parametrized queries** - and you should use `.ExecuteNonQuery()` on your `SqlCommand` object.

Try this code - I tried to *guess* the parameter's data types (assuming the `....ID` ones are `INT`) - adapt as needed, I could be wrong since I don't know what your SQL Server table looks like:

```
if (radioButton1.Checked) 
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Andrej\Desktop\B9PROBA\B9\B9\Database5.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"))
    using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ARB11StavkeRezervacije(RezervacijaID, RBR, KomadID, Datum, KolikoSedista) " + 
                                    "VALUES (@RezervacijaID, @RBR, @KomadID, @Datum, @KolikoSedista)", conn))
    {
        // define and set the parameters
        com.Parameters.Add("@RezervacijaID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        // not sure what datatype this parameter would be - please adapt to match your needs
        com.Parameters.Add("@RBR", SqlDbType.?????).Value = textBox2.Text;
        com.Parameters.Add("@KomadID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = comboBox1.SelectedValue;
        // not sure what datatype this parameter would be - please adapt to match your needs
        com.Parameters.Add("@Datum", SqlDbType.?????).Value =  textBox3.Text;
        com.Parameters.Add("@KolikoSedista", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start;

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close());

            MessageBox.Show("Uspesno Uneti Podaci");
        }
        catch (Exception e1) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e1.Message); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: marc_s It just doesn't work. "failed to convert parameter value from a string to a int32" and does not show me where this mistake is.

Comment: @Csharpclass: well that would have to be that the line with the `Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text)` - setting that first parameter - so obviously, you're **not** entering a valid INT value in that textbox - so maybe that parameter **is NOT** an `INT` datatype?? I have no way of knowing that, since you didn't show us your table structure - so just adapt this as needed ....